# How to pass props to nested routes in React Router 4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a component tree like this:

```
-App
--UserList
---UserItem
---UserItem
---UserItem
--User
```

I'm not being able to pass user data from `UserItem` to `User`. This is what I have:

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { users: [] }

  componentDidMount() {// fetch and setState}

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => <UserList users={this.state.users} />}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }

}
```

UserList.js

```
export default function({ users }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map(user => (
        <UserItem user={user} key={`${user.id}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )

}
```

This is where the problem is: I want to pass the data from the parent component to the child `User` component, instead of having to fetch the user data from the API again.

UserItem.js

```
export default function({ user }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/user">{user.name}</Link>

      <Route path={`/user/${user.name}`} render={() => <User user={user} />} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to implement here. Your app renders the `UserList` when then route is `/`. The `UserList` renders a `UserItem` component for each `user` in the array. Each `UserItem` simply renders a route specific to every user, which will render the `User` component if that route is triggered.

But if I'm not mistaken, the `UserList` will not be rendered if the route is anything but `/`, so if someone accesses `user/...`, the inner routes won't actually exist.

Essentially, this app will not render anything.

If you remove the `exact` keyword from the route in `App`, I think you'll get the result you are looking for. In this case, opening `/user/<USER_NAME>` will render the `User` element for that user.

Your question is regarding passing props into a component through a route, and the mechanism you've used is correct.

`<Route path={...} render={() => <User user={user} />} />`

This is actually right. See the code linked below. On changing the route to `/user/User1`, you'll see the name of "User1" rendered in the app.

See the working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/18w3393767

Comment: Thanks for your response Shishir, you were right with the "exact" prop thing. Now the issue is that the `UserItem`s will be visible when the route is /user/:userName. I want to hide the items  and just show the main `User` component. Here's the updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/7wq1okykq

Comment: `UserItem`s will be visible for all routes, because your `UserList` is designed to render one instance of `UserItem` for every `user` in the array passed to it (Line #21).

If you don't want the `UserItem` to be rendered at all, you can move your route declaration to `UserList`. See https://codesandbox.io/s/480wp337pw

Note that your `Link` elements are also in `UserItem`, so you might want to move them to an appropriate location if you want them to be visible.

In summary, anything that you want to show on on `user/:userName` route should come under the `Route` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.props.users` in the UserItem component

Comment: Using `this.props.users` is not required in `UserItem`. OP is using destructuring assignment to extract `user` from the props passed to the SFC.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but could you pass props like below, here i pass props to render and then to User Component

```
      <Route path={`/user/${user.name}`} render={(props) => <User user={user} {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export default function({ users }) {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.props.users.map(user => ( 
    //mistake here this.props.users.map not users.map 
        <UserItem user={user} key={`${user.id}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: `users.map` is not a mistake because he is using destructuring assignment to get the users variable. In a stateless functional component such as this one, the parameter passed to the function is the `props` object. By using `{users}`, OP is extracting `users` from the props, and discarding the rest.